# System memory is fully utilized while using tape drive software

Tags: memory, redhat-enterprise-linux, tape

I'm using RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.

When using IBM tape drive, it  fully utilizes system memory in only two minutes.

Here is the result of `free -m` command:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4032       3837        194          0          7       3634
-/+ buffers/cache:        195       3837
Swap:         6591          0       6591
```

and when checking the top processes utilization I found the following:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       307 46.3  0.6  95780 27348 ?        Ssl  00:35   3:57 ltfs -o devname=/dev/IBMtape0 /mnt/ltfs
gdm       4033  0.0  0.4  32464 17284 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:00 /usr/libexec/gdmgreeter
root      4020  0.0  0.2  25568 10308 ?        SN   Jul01   0:00 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
root      4007  0.0  0.1  11260  5332 tty7     Ss+  Jul01   0:02 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7
root      3828  0.0  0.1  53360  4988 ?        Ssl  Jul01   0:00 /usr/sbin/cimserver
root      3645  0.0  0.1  13468  4772 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 python ./hpssd.py
68        3549  0.0  0.1   6220  4192 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:01 hald
root      4006  0.0  0.0  27496  3768 ?        Sl   Jul01   0:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-rh-security-token-helper
root      3667  0.0  0.0  10272  3008 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:00 cupsd
```

I'm using a script to take a daily backup on the tape. It copies a cpio file on the tape.

How we can detect the cause of this problem ?

Comment: When issuing the following commands 
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
# sync

they free the memory but it will be fully used again in few seconds

Comment: Looks like a problem with the ltfs command which looks like it is supplied by IBM.

Comment: But this problem recently appeared !!

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking at the wrong value. Your physical memory is 4032 megabytes. Your free memory is 3837. Swap is empty. That is very far from being full. "Cached" memory is free memory! Free memory is used as a disk cache until some program allocates it. In short, you are not out of memory, and there is no problem which needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I got your message. how to overcome this problem

Comment: +1 to reverse downvote.  This answer correctly explains that the system is not out of RAM.  See [linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) for more details.